# How to keep a pointer field constant throughout the lifetime of an object (handle to a pipe in c++)

Tags: c++, winapi, pipe

I am trying to make a handler class for dealing with a pipe in c++. I may start by saying I'm used to c#, and quite new to c++ and the concept of pointers.

The only field in the class is a variable, of type HANDLE (void *), `pipeHandle`, which stores the value returned by `CreateFile()`.

I have a method, `ConnectPipe()`, which uses `CreateFile()` to get the handle of the pipe, as well as some error checking. It stores the handle in `pipeHandle` and then finishes execution. This appears to be problematic, as after research and debugging I have found that the value of `pipeHandle` changes after `ConnectPipe()` finishes executing. I think this is due to the way that the pointer references something instantiated in `ConnectPipe()` which then gets deleted after `ConnectPipe()` finishes.

Code:

PipeManager.h:

```cpp
#ifndef PIPE_MANAGER_H
#define PIPE_MANAGER_H

#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

class PipeManager
{
private:
    HANDLE pipeHandle;
    void PipeConnect(LPCWSTR pipeFullName);
    void PipeReceive(BYTE* outBuffer);

public:
    PipeManager(std::string pipeName);
    void Testing();
};

#endif
```

PipeManager.cpp:

```cpp
#include "PipeManager.h"
#include <iostream>

void PipeManager::PipeConnect(LPCWSTR pipeFullName)
{
    const int ATTEMPT_LIMIT = 10;
    int attempts = 0;

    do {
        if (attempts > ATTEMPT_LIMIT) {
            break;
        }
        pipeHandle = CreateFile(pipeFullName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
        if (pipeHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to connect to the named pipe, error code " << GetLastError() << ". Trying again." << std::endl;
            attempts++;
        }
    } while (pipeHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
}

void PipeManager::PipeReceive(BYTE* outBuffer)
{
    DWORD read = 0; // Number of bytes read in each ReadFile() call
    int index = 0;
    do {
        if (!ReadFile(pipeHandle, outBuffer + index, 1, &read, NULL)) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to read from the named pipe, error code " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    } while (outBuffer[index - 1] != 0); // Stop if the most recent byte was null-termination.
}

// Constructor for a named pipe, yet to be connected to
PipeManager::PipeManager(std::string pipeName) {
    std::string fullName = "\\\\.\\pipe\\" + pipeName;
    PipeConnect(std::wstring(fullName.begin(), fullName.end()).c_str());
}

void PipeManager::Testing()
{
    BYTE buffer[1024];
    PipeReceive(buffer);
}
```

CPPClient.cpp (application entry point):

```cpp
int main()
{
    //return HandlePipe("TestingPipe", false);
    PipeManager pipeManager = new PipeManager(std::string("TestingPipe"));
    pipeManager.Testing();
}
```

I have a pipe server running (written in c#) that creates "TestingPipe", that I know works and have tested. I have also managed to get a pipe client (written in c++) working but not inside a class - just a load of function calls and things in the `main()` method.
When I run the above program, the c# server initially accepts the connection but then fails when the client tries to read saying "pipe is broken", and the c++ client fails with code 6 invalid handle when it tries to read from the pipe.

How can I keep `pipeHandle` constant throughout the lifetime of the object, or at least stop it changing after `ConnectPipe` finishes initialising?

Unless this isn't possible, in which case I'll have to reconnect to the pipe every time I want to read or write to it.

**Edit:**
Removing code that wasn't relevant

Comment: it is a `private` member, you are in complete control of when and how it can be modified. Make it `const` and initialize it in the constructor. Or use a `has_been_set` flag that allows to set it only once

Comment: There is no call to `ConnectPipe` in all of the code, so it's unclear what you are referring to. However, handle values don't just magically change. You have to explicitly assign a new value.

Comment: @IInspectable it's in the constructor - I'm creating the object (calling the constructor) then calling Testing() so it does get called.

Comment: I searched the entire page for `ConnectPipe` and it doesn't exist in the code anywhere.

Comment: I suppose `ConnectPipe` is a typo and should be `PipeConnect`, right?

Comment: anyhow the question is unclear. If you want `PipeConnect` to be only called from within the constructor you can make is `private`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai The problem is I need to initialise it to an expression - a call to CreateFile so I don't think I can make it const?

Comment: Sorry yes I meant PipeConnect

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai PipeConnect is private

Comment: whats the issue then? Why do you think `pipeHandle` would get modified during the lifetime of the `PipeManager` ?

Comment: The code provided is not a [mcve]. Please [edit] the question to provide one that demonstrates the problem in action. The question is not answerable in its current form, and is likely to be closed.

Comment: On a side note: 1) in `PipeReceive()`, `while (outBuffer[index - 1] != 0)` goes out of bounds after the 1st read, so get rid of `-1`. Also, this logic is a buffer overflow waiting to happen. 2) You don't need `const` and non-`const` overloads of `PipeSend()`, the `const` version will suffice by itself. 3) `std::wstring(fullName.begin(), fullName.end())` is not the correct way to convert a `std::string` into a `std::wstring`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai The problem is that pipeHandle changes after `PipeConnect()` finishes executing, so that the `ReadFile()` call fails.

Comment: Educated guess: there's a `~PipeManager` destructor (not shown) that closes the pipe handle, but no user-defined copy constructor. Does the problem remain if you do this in `main`: `PipeManager pipeManager("TestingPipe");` (that is, if you don't construct a temporary PipeManager then copy it into another PipeManager instance)?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Aha that's solved it - I had no idea that that was copying it - thank you very much!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You should post your answer! Or Would Samuel Glover answer yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to Igor Tandetnik - in my `main()` function I had used the `new` keyword, which creates an object and copies it into a new object. It was this that caused the `pipeHandle` to change, not a referencing issue as I first thought.